# Stringstream returning blank value

Tags: c++

Why does this program print out blank?

```
  string str;
  stringstream ss(str);
  ss << "A string";

  cout << str; // just blank
```

Comment: Well, it doesn't print out anything.

Comment: You define str as an empty string, you then create a stringstream ss from str, and write to it. Then you print str. Since nothing has been written to str you see nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stringstream` is not going to modify the argument you pass to its constructor.

Instead, you can get the current buffer from the `stringstream` by calling its `str` member function:

```
cout << ss.str();
```

Next time, consider reading the documentation.

Comment: No, he probably didn't mean that, because then the variable `str` would be meaningless. Rather it's probably a misconception that the string passed to the stream constructor will serve as a buffer.

Comment: @zenith Seems I've gravely misunderstood Stringstream. Thanks for the clarification.